# How to create Concurrent users in Jmeter 2.13

Tags: load, jmeter

13

In order to test concurrent users we have to keep ramp -up period zero .

As concurrent users means users hitting the server at a time in this case we have to set ram-up period zero

Am i correct ?

Answer (score 0):

No, "Ramp-Up Period" just allows your server to "warm-up" a bit. After the ramp up time is over, all users defined with "Number of Threads" will hit your server.

Number of Threads - Number of users to simulate.

Ramp-up Period - How long JMeter should take to get all the threads started. If there are 10 threads and a ramp-up time of 100 seconds, then each thread will begin 10 seconds after the previous thread started, for a total time of 100 seconds to get the test fully up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

No. Setting ramp up to zero will not ensure that all the request will hit the server concurrently.
To do that you need to use "Synchronizing Timer" for the request which you need to send concurrently. This will synchronize the requests of multiple users at a given point and send requests concurrently.

Note: "Synchronizing Timer" need a input - number of concurrent requests to be sent.(should be less than or equal to total number of users)